# How to group mysql results in weeks

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table like this: [image]

I need to sum how many messages were delivered per msisdn in last 8 weeks(but for each week) from date entered. Here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT count(*) as ukupan_broj, SUM(IF (sent_messages.delivered = 1,1,0 )) as broj_dostavljenih, 
count(*) - SUM(IF (sent_messages.delivered = 1,1,0 )) as non_billed,
SUM(IF (sent_messages.delivered = 1,1,0 )) / count(*) as ratio,
`sent_messages`.`msisdn`, 
MONTH(`sent_messages`.`datetime`) AS MONTH, WEEK(`sent_messages`.`datetime`) AS WEEK,
DATE_FORMAT(`sent_messages`.`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE
FROM `sent_messages`
INNER JOIN `received_messages` on `received_messages`.`uniqueid`=`sent_messages`.`originalID` 
and `received_messages`.`msisdn`=`sent_messages`.`msisdn`
WHERE `sent_messages`.`datetime` >= '2016-12-12'
AND `sent_messages`.`originalID` = `received_messages`.`uniqueid`
AND `sent_messages`.`datetime` <= '2017-12-30'
AND  `sent_messages`.`datetime` >=  `received_messages`.`datetime`
AND  `sent_messages`.`datetime` <= ( `received_messages`.`datetime` + INTERVAL 2 HOUR )
AND `sent_messages`.`type` = 'PAID'
GROUP BY WEEK
ORDER BY  DATE ASC
```

And because I'm grouping it by `WEEK`, my result is showing sum of all delivered, undelivered etc. but not per msisdn. Here is how result looks like:
[image]

And when I add `msisdn` in `GROUP BY` clause I don't get the result the way I need it.

**And I need it like this:**

[image]

Please help me to write optimized query to fetch these results for each msisdn per last 8 weeks, because I'm stuck.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

`WEEK(...)` has a problem near the first of the year.  Instead, you could use `TO_DAYS`:

```
WHERE datetime > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 WEEK   -- for the last 8 weeks
GROUP BY MOD(TO_DAYS(datetime), 7)   -- group by week
```

That is quite simple, but there is a bug in it.  It only works if today is the last day of a "week".  And if date%7 lands on the desired day of week.

```
WHERE datetime > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 WEEK   -- for the last 8 weeks
GROUP BY MOD(TO_DAYS(datetime) - 3, 7)   -- group by week
```

Is the first cut at fixing the bugs -- 9-week interval will include the current partial week and the partial week 8 weeks ago.  The "- 3" (or whatever number works) will align your "week" to start on Monday or Sunday or whatever.

`SUM(IF (sent_messages.delivered = 1,1,0 ))` can be shortened to `SUM(delivered = 1)` or even `SUM(delivered)` if that column only has 0 or 1 values.